# VBA .Find, dates, serial number dates, and the data type properties (.Text, .Value, .Value2)

Tags: vba, excel, date

Using the Range.Find Method to iterate through each value in one range to see if it exists in the other. Issue is that the format for both ranges is different (but all the values are ostensibly dates), which results in many "false negatives" (i.e., values are not matching when they should be). is it possible to control the data type for both the input and search ranges so that the system will compare apples-to-apples and successfully recognize matches?

Here is the data and code:

```
Sheet1 (custom format, "yyyy-mm-dd")  
A1  2016-01-01  
A2  2016-01-02  
A3  2016-01-03  
A4  2016-01-04  
A5  2016-01-05  

Sheet2 (text format)  
A1  2016-01-01  
A2  2016-01-03  
A3  2016-01-05  

Sheet3 (display as "yyyy-mm-dd")  
[NO DATA]  

Sheet4 (display as "yyyy-mm-dd")   
[NO DATA]
```

**code:**

```
 Sub FindTest()  
            Dim inputRange As Range  
            Dim searchRange As Range  
            Dim found As Range  
            Set inputRange = Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Resize(7, 1)  
            Set searchRange = Worksheets(2).Cells(1, 1).Resize(5, 1)  
            For Each i In inputRange  
                Set found = searchRange.Find _  
                    (What:=i, _  
                    after:=Cells(1, 1), _  
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _  
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _  
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _  
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _  
                    MatchCase:=False, _  
                    SearchFormat:=False)  
                If Not (found Is Nothing) Then  
                    Worksheets(3).Cells(i.Row, i.Column) = i  
                Else  
                    Worksheets(4).Cells(i.Row, i.Column) = i  
                End If  
            Next i  
        End Sub
```

For this to work, I assume that I need all the value in inputRange and searchRange to be compared as .Text, but I'm not sure to get there.

Comment: Have you considered repairing the data so that apples are apples and not oranges?

Comment: Instead of Searchrange.Find use WHILE loop and compare cell by cell and before compare cast the same to date format and then compare. I think your problem will be resolved by this...

Comment: @Jeeped - We've experimented with that approach but have not been able to figure out how to consistently enforce the desired formatting using PowerQuery. In production, the result is that no matter how we define the date in PowerQuery, the Excel Table produced fails to reflect those formats and VBA reads the data as a date serial number, which means that it is unable to match it to the same date formatted as yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: @PareshJ - I employed similar logic using nested For Each/Next loops, however, I was interested in a more elegant solution because I figured that leveraging a method from the API would be more efficient and less expensive with regards to system load, memory, processing, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep your data as true dates and text-that-looks-like-dates then format the true date values on the he fly to locate matches within the 'text-dates'.

```
Sub FindTest()
    Dim inputRange As Range, i As Range
    Dim searchRange As Range, found As Range

    Set inputRange = Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Resize(99, 1)
    Set searchRange = Worksheets(2).Columns(1)

    For Each i In inputRange
        If IsDate(i) Then                      ' ▼ format into TXT  here ▼
            Set found = searchRange.Find(What:=Format(i.Value2, "yyyy-mm-dd"), _
                            after:=Cells(1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not (found Is Nothing) Then
                With Worksheets(3)
                    .Cells(i.Row, i.Column) = i.Address(external:=True)
                    .Cells(i.Row, i.Column + 1) = i.Address(external:=True)
                End With
            Else
                With Worksheets(4)
                    .Cells(i.Row, i.Column) = i.Address(external:=True)
                    .Cells(i.Row, i.Column + 1) = i.Address(external:=True)
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Alternately, the [Range.Text property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217.aspx) should provide the same answer. Apply the Trim command to make sure that the inputRange dates are not formatted with a trailing `_)` in the format mask.

```
        Set found = searchRange.Find(What:=Trim(i.Text), _
                        after:=Cells(1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

Addendum:

If there is a possibility of leading or trailing spaces in the `searchRange`, then change the parameters of your search to `LookAt:=xlPart`. While repairing the data beforehand would still be the better option, it will ignore extraneous characters that could interfere with a successful match.

If repairing the data can be considered an option then a blanket [Range.TextToColumns method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) on the text values with a YMD [xlColumnDataType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241018%28v=office.12%29.aspx) will quickly convert your `yyyy-mm-dd` 'text-dates' into real dates.

```
    With searchRange
        .TextToColumns Destination: .Cells (1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                       FieldInfo:=Array(0, 5)
    End With
```

This will remove leading/trailing extraneous characters and leave you with a column of true dates.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response! and sorry I wasn't initially clearer. In production, this date will become part of a Unique ID, so I actually want it formatted as Text and not as a Date (I realize that the searchRange is already formatted as Text within the workbook, but I want to control that programmatically as well because there is a chance that the underlying formatting could change). So I need both the inputRange and searchRange converted to (or seen as) Text. If I'm understanding correctly, the first two solutions above convert the inputRange but not the searchRange.

Comment: I attempted to use the TextToColumns per the following but it was not successful. see Answer for code...

Answer (score 0):

TextToColumn code (unsuccessful)

```
Sub FindTest()
Dim inputRange As Range
Dim i As Range
Dim searchRange As Range
Dim found As Range
Set inputRange = Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Resize(7, 1)
Set searchRange = Worksheets(2).Cells(1, 1).Resize(5, 1)
searchRange.TextToColumns Destination:=Worksheets(2).Cells(1), DataType:=xlDelimited, FieldInfo:=Array(1, xlTextFormat)
For Each i In inputRange
    Set found = searchRange.Find _
        (What:=i, _
        after:=Cells(1, 1), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not (found Is Nothing) Then
        Worksheets(3).Cells(i.Row, i.Column) = i
    Else
        Worksheets(4).Cells(i.Row, i.Column) = i
    End If
Next i
```

End Sub